# Insert listview items to mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I have a RecycleView and I want to loop through the all the rows in the RecycleView to find the rows in which the items have not been inserted to the MySQL database yet. I want to upload them automatically into the database if internet connection is available. If upload is successful I want to change the status to inserted. How do I do it?

```
-------------------------
*Item*  |   *Status*    |
-------------------------
Apple  |   Not Inserted |
------------------------- 
Egg   |   Inserted      |
-------------------------
Orange|   Not Inserted  |
-------------------------
```

Comment: For insert you have Edit text, while user editing data in the edit text add them in the db.

Answer (score 1):

You must separate your `presentation` from your `business logic`. Your `recyclerView's` responsibility is just displaying your `data model`. So all you have to do is changing your `data model` and asking `recyclerView` to update `UI`. So you must loop through your `data model` not your `recyclerView` rows.

Solution:

You can loop through all of your `data models` that your `adapter` has  and then put them in a `queue` and upload them one by one.

for example you can pass the `queue` to an `intentService` and start uploading. after finishing you can notify `activity` or `fragment` by using `eventBus`, `Otto`, `LocalBroadcast`. then you update the data model state to `inserted` and notify the adapter that you have done.

**But note that your user may navigate from that activity so persisting your data model in a database and loading and updating it is a cleanest solution.**

Comment: Do you have an example of it ? I am new to android development and I have no idea what a queue is.

Comment: Instead of queue you can use ArrayList, search step by step, for example what is `intentService`? then after understanding go to next step how to pass data to an `intentService`? how to upload data and ....